# How can I show a live stream of video data in my app?

Tags: c#, .net, directx, video-streaming

I get a video feed (mpeg2-ts @ 500kb/s) over the network, but I'm uncertain on how to go from here.

The videofeed is now collected in a rather fast growing byte array, and I need a hint on how to feed a video renderer with these bytes. I've used DirectX's AudioVideoPlayback before, but  as far as I can se it can only read from files, and I wish to avoid disk usage.

**Edit:**
I have never worked with DirectShow, so this could be interesting. Maybe using Media Foundation for best forward compatibility? This stuff is brand new so Google dosn't offer me much help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with DirectShow.  Depending on your exact needs you could render the buffer or let DirectShow handle the networking aspect as well.

Comment: Gave up on DS. It requires more effort than I'm willing to give for a proof-of-concept hobby project. Tagging you as correct answer since it actually is, more details wouldn't hurt though...